# React Native Django Authentication: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, django, react-native, authentication, expo-go

I'm implementing a Django authentication system in my React Native app.

My app.js imports the authentication context, so isLoggedin on app launch is false. The variable isLoggedIn is used in app.js to either render the login screen when isLoggedIn is false, else load AppNavigator which gets the user into the app.

I haven't written the Django backend yet, I'm just setting isLoggedIn to true when the login button is pressed without talking to Django (until I get this problem solved).

The program execution stops at: line 15 of App.js:

const { isLoggedIn } = globalContext;

I've double checked all relevant import statements and believe I'm exporting and importing correctly. Also double checked the import paths.

I also made sure isLoggedin and setIsLoggedIn are in the globalContext variable in AuthContext.js. It is being passed into the Context.Provider in AuthContext.js and App.js is wrapping the whole app  in Provider, so the auth context is available to the whole app.

The app should show the login screen on first load. I should be able to enter some text in the 2 text fields and press the login button to get into the app. However, Expo Go displays the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined" before the login screen appears.

So I reckon the problem exists somewhere in the two source files below. Which is why I haven't included the login screen code, as the Login code isn't executed because the program stops before it's called.

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import {
    AppRegistry,
    View,
} from "react-native";
import SplashScreen from "react-native-splash-screen";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

import AppNavigator from "./Navigation/AppNavigator";
import { Context, Provider } from "./Auth/AuthContext";
import Login from "./Screens/LoginScreen";

export default function App() {
    const globalContext = useContext(Context);
    const { isLoggedIn } = globalContext;
    useEffect(() => {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Provider>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    {isLoggedIn ? <AppNavigator /> : <Login />}
                </NavigationContainer>
            </View>
        </Provider>
    );
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("Provisioner", () => App);
```

AuthContext.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";


const Context = createContext();

const Provider = ({ children }) => {

    const [domain, setDomain] = useState("http://*********.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com:8000");
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [appSettings, setAppSettings] = useState({});

    function initAppSettings() {
        fetch(`${domain}/api/v1.0/app/settings`, {
            method: "GET",
        })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    return res.json();
                } else {
                    throw res.json();
                }
            })
            .then(json => {
                setAppSettings(json);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("Bad JSON");
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        initAppSettings();
    }, []);

    const globalContext = {
        domain,
        isLoggedIn,
        setIsLoggedIn,
        appSettings,
        setAppSettings
    };

    return <Context.Provider value={globalContext}>{children}</Context.Provider>;

};

export { Context, Provider };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the usecontext outside the scope of the provider.
You should move the provider to a level above the component tree.

```
const App = ()=> {
   const globalContext = useContext(Context);
   const { isLoggedIn } = globalContext; 
   ... some code ...
   return someComponent
}

const EnhancementApp =‍ ()=> <Provider><App/></Provider>

AppRegistry.registerComponent("Provisioning", () => EnhancementApp);
```